# Navigate to page | wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have window with `Button` and `Frame`:

```
<Window x:Class="MRE_WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Canvas Height="480" Name="MainCanvas">
        <Button x:Name="wifiAccessPointButton"
                Height="75"
                Background="Red"
                Width="75"
                FontSize="24"
                Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=navigationFrame}"
                CommandParameter="Pages/WebServerPage.xaml">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Wifi"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <Frame x:Name="navigationFrame"
               Height="470"
               Width="622"
               Canvas.Left="88"
               Source="Pages/TempPage.xaml"
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
               Canvas.Top="10"/>

    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And I have two pages:
`TempPage`:

```
<Page x:Class="MRE_WPF.Pages.TempPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="470" d:DesignWidth="622"
      Title="TempPage">

    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and `WebServerPage`:

```
<Page x:Class="MRE_WPF.Pages.WebServerPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="470" d:DesignWidth="622"
      Title="WebServerPage">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="statusLabel"
               Content="Lorem ipsum dolor"
               Foreground="White"
               Width="492"
               Height="70"
               FontSize="28"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I want to open page in navigate frame, when I click button, but it disabled (and if I delete lines related to command from xaml file it will be enabled).

The main question is it possible to use `NavigationCommands` or I should write regular command and use
`NavigationFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/WebServerPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: Personally, I would use usercontrols and an approach called viewmodel first rather than pages. That command is only implemented for a couple of controls. "DocumentViewer and FlowDocumentPageViewer implement support for responding to the GoToPage command, although you are not required to use it; in many cases the implementation in response to that command is the responsibility of the application writer."

Comment: https://github.com/AndyONeill/WPF_NavigationViewModelFirst

Comment: You should use the NavigationService. NavigationCommands is a set of predefined routed commands. They are only command definitions without functionality. The functionality is provided by the control that defines the command bindings for the particular commands. Only a few controls are listening for those commands. This is true for all predefined routed commands e.g. ApplicationCommands. Simply attach a Button.Click handler and use the NavigationService you obtain from the current Page.

Comment: @Andy, thanks a lot, that worked out. You can post it as answer and I'll mark it as solution (though I didn't use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm).